# Flutter align specific widget in column with min width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-column

I'm implementing a chat on my flutter app, and I want my chat-time to be align at the right side of the column (all other widgets should be align left).

My problem is that when I'm using `alignment.bottomRight` in my column, it extends the column width to `max` (and I want to keep it `min`).

The problem:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

my column:

```
return Bubble(
      margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
      elevation: 0.6,
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      nip: BubbleNip.leftTop,
      radius: Radius.circular(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          getUserChatTitle(document['userId']),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, bottom: 5),
            child: SelectableLinkify(
              onOpen: onOpenLink,
              text: "Text Text Text",
              textAlign:
                  intl.Bidi.detectRtlDirectionality(document['content'])
                      ? TextAlign.right
                      : TextAlign.left,
              textDirection:
                  intl.Bidi.detectRtlDirectionality(document['content'])
                      ? ui.TextDirection.rtl
                      : ui.TextDirection.ltr,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                height: 1.35,
                letterSpacing: -0.1,
                fontFamily: 'Arimo',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Text(
              formatTimestampToString(document['timestamp']),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: what is `Column`'s parent widget?

Comment: Bubble https://pub.dev/packages/bubble... I have removed all parents just for checking, same result :\

Comment: Issue is casing for `Buble` parent's width and wrapping with `FittedBox`  solve the width problem but caused Align problem because inner child is getting infinite width.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the `Buble` parent, since removing it still causing the same problem

Comment: Depend on widget tree.  If you wrapped with  Bubble with SizedBox and `Column cross:start`  and  `centerRight` Aligned timeStamp, you will get desire output.

Comment: The parent tree is `ListView` -> `Padding` -> `Bubble` -> `Column`... I have removed the `Padding` and `Bubble` and still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed not as easy, because you want the bubble to have an "undefined" width - it should adapt to the length of the actual message which is not known before actually placing / drawing the widget on runtime. My suggestion would be to make use of a `Stack` - I also used it inside a `ListView.builder` which will probably be the desired use case. Make sure to read my comments in the code block as well:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => UnconstrainedBox(
    /// Decide whether a message has been received or written by yourself (left or right side)
    alignment:
        index % 2 == 0 ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
    /// ConstrainedBox to make sure chat bubbles don't go from left to right if they are too big - you can change it or even remove it if it's not what you want
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5),
      child: Bubble(
        margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
        elevation: 0.6,
        /// Alignment and nip has to be adjusted here too
        alignment:
            index % 2 == 0 ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight,
        nip: index % 2 == 0 ? BubbleNip.leftTop : BubbleNip.rightTop,
        radius: Radius.circular(10),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('TestUser'),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, bottom: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    'Text ' * Random().nextInt(50),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      height: 1.35,
                      letterSpacing: -0.1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                /// Adjust the space you want between the actual message and the timestamp here, you could also use a Text widget to use the same height as the actual timestamp - as you like
                SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Text(
                '08.09.2021',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: it must be accepted answer, Stack + Positioned to bottom the easiest way

Comment: bottom Padding + Stack + Position did solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Text(
              formatTimestampToString(document['timestamp']),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

With:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [Text(
              formatTimestampToString(document['timestamp']),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
        )],
      ),
```

Comment: Try wrapping Row with Expanded